# Visual Studio Debug with Break-point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I create a C# class library using Visual Studio 2010 professional.
The project is .Net 4 based and I can debug it properly attaching to a process.

I convert this project to .Net 3.5 and try to debug, attaching to the same process and with the same break-point as the previous debug: the project does not stop at the break-point.

The break-point has a message on tooltip: `The break point will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.`

I debug the project in a debug mode,
The .pdb and the .dll file are both in the bin folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: What process are you connecting to?  If you change the .net version, you need to rebuild and would need to restart any process that is consuming the dll.

Comment: Check if you are using the most up to date version of the DLL source file.

Comment: @JohnKoerner, Of course I restart the Visual Studio and the process I attach. The process is `Enterprise Architect`- a modeling CASE tool.

Comment: @shahar, Thanks. What do you mean and how could I check it?

Comment: Other than restarting, did you do a clean and a rebuild to ensure that any old binaries have been replaced?

Comment: @jmblack, Yes I did.\